# Configure Ubuntu to run JAR file by double-clicking on it 

Tags: ubuntu, java

In Windows, when I double-clicked on a JAR file it would run the encapsulated Java program.  In Ubuntu, all I get is a list of files stored in the JAR file. Is there a way to configure Ubuntu to run the program instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Right click on any .jar file
- Select **properties**
- Navigate to the **open with** tab in the properties window
- Check off **Sun java 1.x.x Runtime** then hit OK

of course, your version may vary, so replace 1.x.x with your version of the runtime.